# How to get Winmerge to recognize that code can move around?

Tags: c++, winmerge

How to have Winmerge recognize similar code blocks instead of comparing line to line?
Or is there a way to highlight and skip a region to compare to?

[image]

Comment: In [configuration](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Configuration.html) in section Compare > General there is an option "Enable moved block detection".

Comment: @Dialecticus, I tried, didn't do what I thought it would.  Maybe there is more to do with that switch?

Comment: Maybe whitespace is different and so the lines are not identical. Have the files, or just relevant parts of files, available and I can take a look at them.